# How to debug OSGi applications?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, osgi, apache-felix, equinox

I really need to debug my code by the use of breakpoints, however this seems a complex undertaking with an OSGi container.

I have Eclipse and Felix (both the latest). My project is a raw OSGi project, I am not using PDE, just maven bundle plugin to generate the bundles and then copy them to the /bundle folder in felix, then I perform java -jar bin/felix.jar and the project runs. So no fuss here.

However I cannot debug the application that way. I've tried to read the docs (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/development/integrating-felix-with-eclipse.html) but they are outdated/broken and cant make them work...

How can I debug this? Will I have to avoid using OSGi just because debug is not supported...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an IDE tool like bndtools to do the debugging? You can create a repository from your folder of bundles and run them using a bndrun file. This gives you a debug environment in Eclipse which sounds to be what you want. [The bndtools website is here.](http://bndtools.org)

Bndtools also does a lot more, but it sounds as if you're happy with your existing Maven build. The tutorial runs through setting up a basic workspace, but the main thing you'll be interested in is [Running a framework](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html#run-an-osgi-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Start felix with the following parameters to enable remote debugging.

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 -jar bin/felix.jar
```

After you can connect via Eclipse Remote Debugging to your Felix Container.

1. Run
2. Debug Configurations
3. Remote Java Application
4. Choose as project the project/sources you want to debug
5. Configure port to 1044
6. Trigger debugger by clicking on debug